# Do I need to submit sub-sitemap as well?

Tags: web, seo, sitemap

i've a website with root sitemap. The root sitemap is describe all the sub-sitemap. Do I need to submit sub-sitemap as well, when I submit to google or others directories?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to submit only root sitemap. It should contain links to all your sub-sitemaps.